# MySQL update the column with conditions

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to update (middle name - mname) a database table based on a certain condition. SQLfiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c022/2

I would like to know `HENRY {null} FORD` is belonging to one of other `HENRY {A,B} FORD` based on the coauthors and update the table.

The author with `null` middle name is updated with the middle name of the author with the same first and last name and with whom he has more number of common co-authors.

For example, based on the data the results is:

```
HENRY       FORD    HENRY FORD  ---> this should be updated 'B' due to more common authors
HENRY   A   FORD    HENRY A FORD
HENRY   B   FORD    HENRY B FORD
```

However,

```
JACK        SMITH   JACK SMITH  ---> this shouldn't be updated due to no common authors 
JACK    A   SMITH   JACK A SMITH
JACK    B   SMITH   JACK B SMITH
```

Any suggestions are appreciate.

Comment: You may use union function of mysql. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: @jewelhuq I don't understand how 'union' can be a solution. do you understand the question?

Comment: Looking at the feed, and I still do not understand what you trying to achieve... What's the difference between the two examples... Why Ford should be updated, and Smith shouldn't?
please clarify more

Comment: @cyadvert because JACK {null} SMITH has no common coauthors of JACK {A, B} SMITH. So leave it. However, HENRY {null} FORD has one common author with HENRY B FORD. So I want to update his middle name with 'B'. Clear?