# MySQL SELECT the number of common names in different rows

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to find the number of common (friends) in different rows.
Here is the sample table.

```
    name            friends
JACK SMITH     HENRY FORD,JAMES ANDERSON, ADAM SMITH
JACK A SMITH   CARL ERIKSON
JACK B SMITH   HENRY FORD,JAMES ANDERSON
```

I want to know how many common friends they have. The results is:

```
    name            friends                              num-common-friends
JACK SMITH     HENRY FORD,JAMES ANDERSON, ADAM SMITH     
JACK A SMITH   CARL ERIKSON                              0 -> he has zero common friends with JACK SMITH
JACK B SMITH   HENRY FORD,JAMES ANDERSON                 2 -> he has two common friends with JACK SMITH
```

I am not interested in the number of common friends of `JACK SMITH` who has no middle name.

The table structure is :
(`id`, `fname`,`mname`,`lname`, `name`)

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd highly recommend looking into normalizing your database. If possible, split the friends into a new table (1-n) and this makes this question a lot easier...

Comment: Alternatively, don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: I agreed with both of you. Then, can you see the previous question? This question is following from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021474/mysql-update-the-column-with-conditions

Comment: the column of friends is result from `group_concat()`.

Comment: If you could provide the table structures, that would be great.

Comment: You sample data disagrees with your "table structure".  Please edit.